# Irreducible element from integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am really confused on the concept of irreducible element.

My professor said

Let D be an integral domain, $p\in D$ s.t $p$ is a nonzero nonunit element.

Then $p \in D$ is called an irreducible element of $D$ if $p=ab$ ($a,b \in D$) then $a$ is unit or $b$ is a unit.

But my book says

Then $p \in D$ is called an irreducible element of $D$ if $p=ab$ ($a,b \in D$) then either $a$ is unit or $b$ is a unit.

I am confused because of "either". So from my book, if $a$ is unit, then does it mean $b$ is not a unit?

For example, a sentence: You should to answer with either yes or no.

It feels like choosing only one, not two of them can be chosen.

Or, is it independent? My mother tongue is not English so it is hard to get it.

Comment: Both sentences are saying the same thing. At least one of them is a unit.

Comment: Both mean the same in English.

Comment: The second definition is more accurate since excludes explicitly the case when $a$ and $b$ are both units, that is, by definition an irreducible element is not a unit.

Comment: In math there is generally no distinction between "this or that" and "either this or that." The either is a filler that has no meaning, and in particular it does not imply exclusive or. The standard practice is that or is inclusive because inclusive or is used so much more often.

Comment: The correct phrasing should be: "either $a$ is a unit, or $b$ is a unit, *or both*", but in English, people often imply the exclusiveness of the word "or"  through *context*. Often, a text will clarify what "or" means (mathematically) in an earlier section, but this is not always the case. In math, "or" is non-exclusive, unless otherwise specifically stated to be exclusive. The confusion with "ordinary English" sentences (such as your example) is unfortunate, and I fully understand your confusion.